I'm trying to merge one pandas main data frame and multiple data values ​with actual data values
I have a main dataframe



Title
URL
2015
2016
2017
.... 2024




Title A
URL A
NAN
NAN
NAN
NAN


Title B
URL B
NAN
NAN
NAN
NAN



and a sub-dataframe (filename : Title)



2015
2016
2017
.... 2024




10
20
30
1821793



I have a lot of other sub-dataframes as well.
I would like to work on Python code by matching the sub dataframe to the format of the main dataframe. Ultimately, I want to create a csv file. What should I do?

It seems to me like you should read in each "sub dataframe", create a list of all of them, concatenate them, then merge them with the "main" to get the url column, if that's all the "subs" are missing.

please provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can give you an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

also, stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, you need to show us what you've already tried and why it doesn't work
